# Move view exposed filter in header Drupal 8

Tags: php, drupal-8

How to move exposed filter into header? I have tried every possible solution. I have created view which has exposed filter in block but block is not showing in admin/structure/block. I have even enabled Use AJax to Yes.

I have tried this solution but it is not working in drupal 8 [Expose Filter](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/50223/expose-filter-in-block-to-show-results-on-view-page)

Any help would be great

Comment: Can you please provide some context. For instance some minimal, reproducable code for your problem. For guidance please check the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page

Comment: @5th I have added reference link that I tried. Thank you

Comment: Is your view a page view or block view?